# tag input - place div on top of input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new developer and am trying to create a tags input - there are lots of solutions (plugins, etc) but I'd like to try to do this with just html/css if I can from this point on. how can I make the input tags *appear* on top of the input? Is there anyway to position them on top of the input, without messing around with input values?

```
<div class="edit">
<div class="filter-tags-cloud" ng-show="editMode" style="float:left;">
    <div ng-repeat="filterTag in tags track by $index" class="filter-tag">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-filter">
            <span class="btn btn-filter-tag filter-truncate">{{filterTag}}</span>
            <span class="btn btn-filter" ng-click="vm.removeTag($index)">
                <span ng-click="removeTag($index)" class="fa fa-times"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="input" style="float:right;">
    <input type="text" ng-show="editMode" class="edit" ng-model="frontSeal.selected" ng-keydown="checkEvent($event)"/>
</div>
```

what it looks like now:
[image]

I would like the spans with the filter tags to be inside the inputs or at least appear so.

Comment: wrap both of them with another div with position: relative and set one of them position: absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this help, try add this in your css

```
.filter-tags-cloud {position:relative; top:10px;}
```

This can push from top the "filter-tags-cloud" from current position